# Error in calling Azure rest API -The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-data-lake, informatica, informatica-cloud

i am calling Azure Rest API to list all blobs in a directory (inside container) throuh informatica cloud using web service transformation.But i am getting error while running the mapping `InvalidUri`The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
API: https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/training?restype=container&comp=list&prefix=training/Type/Class

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce your issue, the REST API - [`List Blobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) works fine on my side.

You could refer to the sample below, make sure you are using it the same as mine.

**Note:** When you using `prefix`, you have already used the container name `training` in the url, don't use it again in the parameter, it should be `prefix=Type/Class`.

Request URL:

```
GET https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/training?restype=container&comp=list&prefix=Type/Class
```

Request header:

```
x-ms-version = 2019-12-12
```

Test in the postman:

[image]

My storage structure:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response.It does work with the postman.While calling the API from informatica cloud, it throws error.I have created the swagger file for this rest API.Using this file in IICS to extract the details in a file .